# iPad Video Sizing/Format

Tags: ios, ipad, video, adobe, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need a full screen portrait video like the following: [image]
What should my export settings be in Adobe After Effects. I know that iPad supports h.264 and up to 640x480.  But I need it to fill the 1024x768 in portrait mode.  As long as I get the final video looking just as it does in the screenshot is all that matters (meaning no black bars on the sides or anything, just fullscreen video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad will happily play 720x1280 h.264 video.

So, in your situation, you should be able to render your video out at a width of 768 pixels, and with a corresponding vertical size that matches your video's aspect ratio correctly.